# How to change php URLS with SEO-friendly apache URLS?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

So I'm pulling events from the database such as `/event-detail.php?id=1`, but I want it to look like /Event-Name/ instead.  How do I achieve this?  I know a bit about mod Apache rewrite but not enough to know if it would work here.  Or am I approaching this wrong?  Do I need to pull items with name instead? `/event-detail.php?name=Event Name`?  I don't really want to do it that way even though it seems like it would be much easier.

Comment: What is your mod_rewrite question, specifically?  What have you tried?

Comment: My question is if it's possible to convert /event-detail.php?id=1 to /Event-Name/?  I'm assuming no since apache would never know how what the name of id 1 is, but just confirming.  And I guess I'm interested how those things are usually done.  Hard to think of how to put this into words to search for it.

Comment: Apache doesn't care, or need to know about the name of your event.  It's up to your scripts in PHP to handle the input.  Apache can be configured to pass the fake directory as a parameter.  See the answer to your post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very hard to make it work otherwise (I think).

Try this (write this to server conf or .htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ event-detail.php?name=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

That will rewrite urls and forward everything else than existing files and directories to `event-detail.php` script.

Bit more info, if user call's `/myShowEvent1` that will be rewritten as `event-detail.php?name=myShowEvent1` or if user call's `/event/25366273` that would be same as calling `event-detail.php?name=event/25366273` (that is if they do not exists in the server).

Comment: Good deal, this is a great starting point.  I understand more now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

But remember all the links u have on the page must ba absolute not relative.

Just try yourself and you will know what i am talking about.